# Log in to Disqus with StackExchange OpenID

Tags: support, openid, authentication, stack-exchange-openid

Disqus shows three fields on their [login page](http://disqus.com/profile/login/?next=https://disqus.com/): "Username or Email", "Password", and "OpenID URL". If you put `https://openid.stackexchange.com` into "OpenID URL" (as instructed on [SE's blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/)) and click Login, you're rejected with "*We couldn't log you in. Please check what you've entered*." What is the correct approach to log in to Disqus with a StackExchange OpenID?

(My understanding about OpenID is that I should only be typing the StackExchange OpenID endpoint URL into this form. Correct me if I'm wrong. Also, please forgive the relatively newb question and that I couldn't find a better place to ask.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be unrelated to Stack Exchange OpenId in particular. I've tried several OpenId providers (Stack Exchange, a delegated version, MyOpenId, Blogger, and Wordpress); Disqus gives me that error message you encountered for all of them.

The way you've tried *should* work.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I wrote their customer support, and they replied they're dropping OpenID as a login mechanism. They claimed it should still work for now, but clearly that's not the case. Not going to pursue it.

Answer (score 1):

Disqus is flipping weird, and different logins work in different places. If you go to a blog which uses traditional-style Disqus comments, you can log in in a number of ways, including OpenID. If you go to a blog which uses new-style Disqus comments, you cannot log in with OpenID (but if you're already logged in with OpenID elsewhere, you are still logged in there). I have never managed to log in on the Disqus site itself.

Ultimately, this is a Disqus problem, not a Stack Exchange problem.